# Find lines with exact string bash

Tags: bash

I need to find all lanes which contains exact string, for example we have this input:

`/home/admin fileA
 /home/admin/bin fileB`

and I need to find line

`/home/admin fileA`

I suppose I should use `grep /home/admin` but it don’t work the way I want to even with `-w`

Comment: because it will find all lanes wich contains "/home/admin" and that means output would be 
`/home/admin fileA     
 
 /home/admin/bin fileB`

Comment: sorry I didn't mean to delete my comment: it was: "why doesn't grep work for you?" ...

It works, you just need to be more specific with what you're searching.

Comment: because it find every lines with it even when it is substring so it will print the second line too, and i need to find only exact string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '$1 == "/home/admin"' file
/home/admin fileA
```

**EDIT:** As per comment below you can use:

```
awk -v p=$(pwd) '$1 == p' file
```

Using `grep`:

```
grep -F '/home/admin ' file
/home/admin fileA
```

Comment: that grep dont work for me it ll write even the next line because it substring in it

Comment: There is a space after `admin` in my suggested `grep` command to make sure `'/home/admin/bin` isn't matched. In anycase `awk` solution is better here.

Comment: but i have a problem that in my script i use `pwd` command wich does not work in that quotes

Comment: See updated answer, you can use: `awk -v p=$(pwd) '$1 == p' file`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73371/discussion-between-michael-halinar-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1):

Grep would work if you want to find anything that starts with `/home/admin` but not `/home/admin/`.

```
grep '^/home/admin[^/]' file
```

the `[^/]` means "anything BUT a slash"

Comment: but in my script i use `pwd` command instead that /home/admin wich dont work inside the `' '` apostrophes

Answer (score 1):

Search for your term followed by a space or the end of line

```
grep '/home/admin\($\|[[:blank:]]\)' file
```

or, a little tidier

```
grep -E '/home/admin($|[[:blank:]])' file
```

`grep -w` does not work because it wraps your search term in word boundary markers, and, for the 2nd line, there is a word boundary between `admin` and `/`

Comment: but there is a problem that `/home/admin` is output of `pwd` command, wich will not work because of `' '`

Comment: simple enough: `grep -E "$(pwd)"'($|[[:blank:]])' file` -- just concatenating 2 quoted strings